# Section component is not showing on nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend

Im coding my nextjs portfolio but when i try to import my about section component it didnt work.

Here is my page.js

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import Hero from '@/components/HeroSection';
import AboutMe from '@/components/AboutMe';

export default function Home() {
  return (
     <main className='main'>
      <Hero />
      <AboutMe />
      </main>     
      
      
    
   
  )
}
```

I tried to make all from scratch but it didnt work.

Comment: kindly share your `tsconfig.json/jsconfig.json` and `AboutMe` file code

Comment: Here is my jsconfig.json : 
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}

And my About section: 
const AboutMe = () => {
return (
<section>
all the code
</section>

export default AboutMe;

Comment: other component is showing?

Comment: Yes, my hero component. A hero section with an h1, typing text effect, description  and a picture.